# UNIX processes: fork() and wait()

Tags: unix, fork, wait, waitpid

this is my question on `fork()` and the respective `wait()` that will take place:

In my `main()`, I call a function, let's say `function()` that uses the `fork()` system call,  but I want `function()` to return without waiting for the children to terminate, and thus `main()` has to wait for them before terminating.

So, is it possible for `main()` to call `wait()` on children that have been `fork()`ed in the body of another function called my this `main()`?

If yes, do I have to pass the children's pid's to `main()` through a variable?

Answer (score 2):

If I follow the question correctly, you want to have something like this:

- `main` calls `function`
- `function` calls `fork` to create child/ren, and returns in the parent process
- `main` later calls `wait` on the child/ren

This is fine… Nominally, you don't *have to* pass the child(ren)'s PID(s) back to `main`, because you can just call `wait` to reap any child process that happens to exist; however, to use `waitid` or `waitpid`, you would need/want to provide them back up to `main`. You could either return the PID to `main` in a structure like a linked list or NULL-terminated array, or create some kind of file-scoped or global variable to contain the list.

There's a pretty good breakdown in the Linux manual page for `wait(2)` (`man 2 wait` or so)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, main can wait for children which forked in sub-functions. wait () waits for any child to terminate.

You will still want to pass the return value of fork() to the main function, because you will need it to decide whether you are the child or the parent process.